# How do I zipalign my signed apk?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, keystore, sign, zipalign

I got the below output when i tried to zipalign my signed apk using the command:

zipalign -v 4 C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\Focus.apk C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\Focus-zipaligned.apk
 [image: Command Prompt]

Here, I don't see anything that says zipalignment was performed successfully. Please help me zipalign my signed apk file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it help if you write the apk-paths in quotes? Seeing as you have spaces in the paths, it might screw things up :)

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg I just tried it..but it gave the same output.

Comment: Can you show the command you typed with the quotes on?

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg Hey..i got it fixed! :) first i used single quotes...and that didn't work..Later I tried double quotes and got it right! Thank you so much for the help! Have a good day!!:)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. All I had to do was, put my apk paths in quotes since some folders had spaces. Thanks to @FredrikWiderberg for the suggestion.